# Python socket client unable to re-connect

Tags: python, sockets

I have two buttons. Connect and Disconnect. When connect is pressed the first time, the client successfully connects to the server (localhost:4106) and when when disconnect is pressed the client disconnects.
My problem is that when I press "Connect" again, the client will not re-connect to the server and I get an error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/InlBD.png

I think this is caused because a socket connection cannot be re-used? Is there a workaround for this? Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/python          

import socket               
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

top = Tkinter.Tk()

s = socket.socket()       
host = '127.0.0.1' 
port = 4106              

def connect():
    s.connect((host, port))

def disconnect():
    s.close()

ConnectBtn = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Connect", command = connect)

DisconnectBtn = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Disconnect", command = disconnect)

ConnectBtn.pack()
DisconnectBtn.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Call socket.socket() again in connect and assign s to a new socket. Put a check in disconnect() to make sure it's an valid open socket before you close it.

Comment: Sockets cannot be reused; use `s = socket.socket()` in the `connect()` function, and replace the declaration of `s` at the top of the code to `s = 0`. You can also use your `disconnect()` function to close the socket only if it's a valid socket by checking if its value is `0`, and making the function set it its value to `0` once it has successfully disconnected it. I think that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to rewrite this code tcl/tk in python, but can be a good start for a solution. [Here is the code shared by Scott Nichols](http://wiki.tcl.tk/12379). This code show how  the client will be able to automatically reconnect to the server if the connection was lost.

I use with success for automatic reconnect to the server this code:

```
def open_connection():
    data0=''

    try:
        # Create a TCP/IP socket
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

        # Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
        server_address = ('192.168.0.100', 8000)
        sock.settimeout(10)     # TimeOut 5 secunde

        while True:

            try:
                sock.connect(server_address)
                message = 'new connection'
                sock.sendall(message)

                # Look for the response
                amount_received = 0
                data0=sock.recv(1024)
                amount_received = len(data0)
                return

            finally:
                wNET = 0
                pass

    except:
        sock.close()
        time.sleep(60)
        del data0
```